# Authentication in email forwarding between SMTP servers

Tags: php, email, smtp, forwarding, smtp-auth

I am writing a Mail Relay Server in PHP for Newsletter mailings.
This server encodes all links in the e-mails so that they point to an accompanying website for tracking (click count only) and redirecting.

This Mail Relay Server will run as a service for multiple customers sending Newsletters.
Each customer has it's own credentials for the Mail Relay Server.
The newsletters may go to a great amount of recipients.

As of this, I can't forward all mails through my own mail account (would bring my webhoster on the blacklist).
This is why I thought of forwarding them to the recipients' mail server myself, using the techniques used in e-mail forwarding all around the world.

My question now is: Is there a way to forward e-mails from an own SMTP server to another, for which I don't have a mail account and cannot send credentials?

Thanks in advance for any help and clarification on this.

Comment: This is called "running your own mail server", and you'll run into the same reputation issues as sending the email via your ISP's mail server. Unless you have a lot of spare time that you want to spend begging various and sundry ISPs to accept your mail, then I would suggest signing on with a mailing service that will handle your outbound mail for you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Sammitch, but there are services doing just what I want to do already. But they are either expensive, or do not work properly. Altogether their only restriction for the sender is a limited amount of mails per hour, and that's what I can do too. But if I forward the mails of multiple customers (say for example 10 customers) through my ISP, then I must send the multiple amount (10 times in this example). Therefore I need to forward those mails to the final SMTP servers without any relays in between. There must be a way, others do it too.